# Cómo ocultar columnas de tabla HTML con jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, jquery

busco la forma de ocultar las columnas de una tabla que posee columnas de fechas. Aquí está el ejemplo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.table
{
width:700px;
}

</style>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="tble">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th class="7">2019-08-01</th>
      <th class="8">2019-09-01</th>
      <th class="9">2019-10-01</th>
      <th class="10">2019-11-01</th>
      <th class="11">2019-12-01</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Juan</td>
        <td class="7">Comprado</td>
        <td class="8">Comprado</td>
        <td class="9">Sin comprar</td>
        <td class="10">Sin comprar</td>
        <td class="11">Sin comprar</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Patricio</td>
        <td class="7">Comprado</td>
        <td class="8">Comprado</td>
        <td class="9">Sin comprar</td>
        <td class="10">Sin comprar</td>
        <td class="11">Sin comprar</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).on('ready',function(){

$('#tble > thead > tr > th,#tble > tbody > tr > td').each(function (){  
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getMonth(); 
        var tipo_clase=$(this).attr("class");

        if(tipo_clase >= n)
        {
          $("." + tipo_clase).show();
        }
        else if(tipo_clase < n)
        {
          $("." + tipo_clase).hide();
        }                
});
  
});
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Bueno, como pueden notar dentro de mi código hay un tabla que contiene fechas como columnas, ingresé un jquery que obtiene el mes actual **var n = d.getMonth();** y agregué un *if* que indica que si ese valor es mayor a la clase de las columnas se van a mostrar, y un *else* que ocultará el mes anterior (el mes de agosto, ha sido oculto en el ejemplo).
Lamentablemente me funciona muy bien al crear la tabla con los datos como en el ejemplo.
El problema es que trabajo con datos que provienen desde MySQL, por lo que se oculta sólo los encabezados **thead > tr > th** , pero no los datos que realmente son lo que importan.
¿Alguna idea respecto a esto?, si no logro hacerlo en jquery, puedo hacerlo desde backend a través de php ?

Comment: El código funciona. Cuál es la diferencia a la hora de crear la tabla con los datos de MySQL? Evidentemente algo distinto estás haciendo. Generá una tabla con datos de MySQL y pegá acá el HTML generado.

Comment: ¿Qué datos te vienen de MySQL? Seguramente sea un problema de conversión de fechas